# Programmatically Focus AutoCompleteBox

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

when clicking into my autocompletebox, I have an event that triggers and it'll populate my autocompletebox's collection. While populating the collection, I have a progressbar appear and when that appears, my autocompletebox seems to lose focus. In order to start typing into the autocompletebox, I then have to do a second click into the autocompletebox. This is a bit tedious and may annoy my clients.

May I ask how do I focus telerik's autocompletebox?

```
public async void InitializeCollectionAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Atts.Any())
    {
        await Run(BuildAttendees);            
    }
}
```

The progress bar is within Run method. I tried the below after awaiting, same result.

```
var autocompleteBox = sender as RadAutoCompleteBox;
autocompleteBox.Focus();
```

I also tried below

```
public async void InitializeCollectionAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Atts.Any())
    {
        await Run(BuildAttendees);

        var autocompleteBox = sender as RadAutoCompleteBox;
        var waterMarkTextBox = autocompleteBox.ChildrenOfType<RadWatermarkTextBox>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (waterMarkTextBox != null)
        {
            waterMarkTextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `AutoCompleteBox` from the WPFToolkit ?

Comment: no it's from telerik